# PHP insert into not inserting any data

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-insert

I have a php statement to insert a bit of information into my mySQL database. the connection works perfectly. The problem I am having is I am getting the following error code:

> Error: INSERT INTO tasks ('taskName', 'requestedBy', 'details',
>   'dateAdded') VALUES ('test1' ,'test3' ,'test3', 2015-01-05') You have
>   an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''taskName',
>   'requestedBy', 'details', 'dateAdded') VALUES ('test1' ,'test3' ,'te'
>   at line 1

the function is as follows

```
if(isset($_POST["submitTask"])){
    insertTask();
};

function insertTask(){
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "tasktrack";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "tasktrack";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$taskname = $_POST["task_name"];
$requestedby= $_POST["requested_by"];
$details = $_POST["details"];
$datenow = date("Y-m-d");

$sql = "INSERT INTO tasks ('taskName', 'requestedBy', 'details', 'dateAdded') VALUES ('$taskname' ,'$requestedby' ,'$details', $datenow')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
};
```

I have tried multiple different solution with the `$sql` line as seen below

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tasks ('taskName', 'requestedBy', 'details', 'dateAdded') VALUES ('$taskname' ,'$requestedby' ,'$details', $datenow')";

$sql = "INSERT INTO tasks (taskName, requestedBy, details, dateAdded) VALUES ($taskname ,$requestedb ,$details, $datenow)";

$sql = "INSERT INTO tasks (`taskName`, `requestedBy`, `details`, `dateAdded`) VALUES (`$taskname` ,`$requestedb` ,`$details`, `$datenow`)";
```

Now I am just stuck and can't think of any more things to try.

Comment: All your 3 attempts are wrong. The first one, just remove the quotes for the columns and you will be jumping with joy ;-) and missing quote for `$datenow'` in the first.

Comment: You need backticks for the column- and table names (if any...) and straight single or double quotes for the values. And you should escape your values or use a prepared statement to avoid sql injection.

Comment: Backticks are for table and field names.  Single (or double) quotes are for string values.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections; you should read on [how to prevent them in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Comment: Also based on your code example you are currently missing a ' around `$datenow`. I see `$datenow'`

Comment: @Diemuzi ah yes, good catch on that.

Comment: Just for clarification:  ` - backtick, ' - single-quote. And you should really do something about those sql injections, remember little Bobby Tables, http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tasks (taskName, requestedBy, details, dateAdded) VALUES ('$taskname' ,'$requestedby' ,'$details', '$datenow')";

// Removed quotes from columns, and added missing quote on datenow
```

Please note, this technique for adding values into the database is very insecure, and is prone to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: not asking about the vulnerability because it will only ever be on my laptop locally as it is a personal system. I have tried this previously too

Comment: Blargh, when everything happens within 30 seconds of each other, duplicates happen.

Comment: @Kieranmv95 That's not important; you will break your own query whenever you insert for example a text containing a `'` character.

Comment: I know these  things already, and it will probably be fixed at a later dateas i onyl started this half hour ago XD anyway it did work the fix thankyou, will accept in 8 minutes

Comment: @Blake Well, it turned out okay in the end :-)

Answer (score 0):

You must not enclose the field names in apostrophes or quotes. Either enclose them in back quotes (`) or use them as they are.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tasks (`taskName`, `requestedBy`, `details`, `dateAdded`) VALUES ('$taskname' ,'$requestedby' ,'$details', '$datenow')";
```

or

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tasks (taskName, requestedBy, details, dateAdded) VALUES ('$taskname' ,'$requestedby' ,'$details', '$datenow')";
```

However, if the field name is a MySQL keyword or if it contains spaces, quotes, commas, parenthesis, operators or other characters that have special meaning in SQL then you have to enclose them in back quotes or MySQL will report a syntax error at the special character.